# Fullpage.js - Change Dotted Nav to Icon Set

Tags: icons, nav, fullpage.js

I would like to change fullpage.js dotted nav to an icon set. Each icon will represent each section. How can I manage to do that?
Cannot find any solution of this.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to give some more details on what you've tried and what hasn't worked. The question as it stands is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating your own navigation bar?

Use `navigation:false`.

Then create you own nav and use apply the method [`fullpage_api.moveTo`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movetosection-slide) in each of the elements.

[Reproduction online](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/vYXQRYG)

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    licenseKey: 'YOUR KEY HERE',
    navigation: false,
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
        activateNavItem($('#my-nav').find('li').eq(destination.index));
    },
    afterRender: function(){
        activateNavItem($('#my-nav').find('li').eq($('.section.active').index()))
    }
});

$('.fa-bell').click(function(){
    var destination = $(this).closest('li');
    fullpage_api.moveTo(destination.index() + 1 );
});

function activateNavItem(item){
    item.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

With my list using [font-awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/):

```
<ul id="my-nav">
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thank you @Alvaro

Comment: Another question, and how to point the first navigation to the second section since I plan to start the navigation on the second section onwards?

Comment: Just sum another number in here: `$.fn.fullpage.moveTo`:  Use `destination.index() + 2`

Comment: @Alavro, could you show how to make an active item will be shown only in the middle of the list? means that when we click the nav item, and selected item will transform to the middle of the list item as an active item?