# How to change horizontal slide navigation dots into links with words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js and would like to change the horizontal nav dots into words (or normal links) instead of the dots. This is the horizontal nav example: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationH.html#secondPage

I'm not good with javascript, so the only place inside jquery.fullpage.js I found where i could insert this was iside the  in this part:

```
    for(var i=0; i< numSlides; i++){
            nav.find('ul').append('<li><a href="#"><span>someones name</span></a></li>');
```

The problem is that it adds "Someone's name here" underneath each dot, and so I don't know how to have different names under different dots. How do I separate each slide dot and anchor, and what should my html look like?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want a quick and easy way to add a different name per dot, you could have an array of names `var names = ['a','b','c']` and then use those inside the loop e.g. `.append('<li>' + names[i] + '</li>');` (Simplified append for readability)

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me where to put this in the code?

Comment: If you just replace the snippet in your question with the JS at this link, it should show the names you're after. (You will need to replace the `'a','b'...` with your names of choice) https://jsfiddle.net/fz6z1148/

Comment: Thank you so much, just what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as [this other answer regarding using icons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742906/1081396).

Basically creating your own nav and binding to it fullpage.js functions.

Answer (score 0):

How about just add this. You can have both dots and caption.

```
navigationTooltips: ['Home', 'Second page', 'Third and last page'],
showActiveTooltip: true,
```

C