# fullpage.js how to create slide custom image navigation dots?

Tags: custom-controls

I am using fullPage.js fullpage slider in my project. but i need the customized image as navigation dots. I searched the fullPage documentation also. but i cant find out the solutions. Anybody know about this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code and it will solve your needs.

```css
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span{
    background-image:  url("../img/bullets.png");
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

This css code enable bullet images on your slider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `menu` option. 
You can create any kind of menu / nav with it and it will add the `active` class where it should.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **menu:** (default false) A selector can be used to specify the menu to link with the sections. This way the scrolling of the sections will activate the corresponding element in the menu using the class active. **This won't generate a menu but will just add the active class to the element in the given menu with the corresponding anchor links**. In order to link the elements of the menu with the sections, an HTML 5 data-tag (data-menuanchor) will be needed to use with the same anchor links as used within the sections. Example:

Just use a class if you want to have multiple menus / navs.

`menu: '.myNav'`

Otherwise, you can also use the [fullPage.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) or the [fullPage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) to activate and desactivate the elements of any nav or menu.

Check [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742906/1081396).