# Fixed/scrolling nav on fullpage.js section page

Tags: html, navigation, anchor, fullpage.js, sections

I'm trying to get the fixed navigation in the example below to work with fullpage.js
http://turnwall.com/demos/webdev_part11/index.html
http://www.turnwall.com/articles/adding-single-page-scrolling-navigation-to-your-site/

The issue I'm having is the active state isn't showing depending on which anchor has passed/clicked. The only thing I've differed is not using section ID's as the reference/anchor ID (need same class for sections in order for fullpage.js to work).

Also aware fullpage.js has it's own built-in nav, however, I need the flexibility of one active 'anchor' referring to/being active on a few sections, and not just displaying every single section in the nav.

Would appreciate any advice!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.combinedScroll.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="fullpage">

<nav class="site-navigation page-navigation">
  <ul div="menu">
    <li class=""><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="#next">One</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#next">Two</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="section" data-color="red">
<div id="right"><img id="sweets" src="work/hav-2.png"/></div>
</div>
   <div class="section" data-color="indigo">
</div>
    </div>
     <div class="section" data-color="grey">
     <div id="next">NEXT PROJECT  ↓</div>

     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need the flexibility of one active 'anchor' referring to/being
>   active on a few sections, and not just displaying every single section
>   in the nav.

Just create your own menu as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43114561/1081396).
No need to use the `menu` option in that case. As you want a much more custom menu that will activate the same element for multiple sections.