# Fullpage.js - new navigation bar for slides

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have the next code (extract from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733560/fullpage-js-change-dotted-nav-to-icon-set/36742906#36742906)) for create a new navigation bar for sections thats works great:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1216/)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        activateNavItem($('#my-nav').find('li').eq(nextIndex-1));
    },
    afterRender: function(){
        activateNavItem($('#my-nav').find('li').eq($('.section.active').index()))
    }
});

$('.fa-bell').click(function(){
    var destination = $(this).closest('li');
    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(destination.index() + 1 );
});

function activateNavItem(item){
    item.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

using font-awesome icons:

```
<ul id="my-nav">
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>
```

My question is if there are a way for do the same but for horizontal "slides" instead of "sections"?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Just make use of the slides callbacks for that, such as:

- [onSlideLeave](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onslideleave-anchorlink-index-slideindex-direction-nextslideindex)
- [afterSlideLoad](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex)

And apply the same logic.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro for your help and for your amazing work.

Comment: Sadly @Alvaro my knowledge is very limited and i can't  get it to work. I've been playing with the code all night without success.