# How can i customize navigation dots in fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js in my project. I used div id menu for navigation and menu, but I want to customize the navigation dots on the right side of the screen so that the last dot navigate to the first page while the first dot navigates to the last page.

I would like to arrange the navigation dots in descending order. Is it possible?

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage',{
  autoScrolling: true,
  navigation: true,
  anchors: ['part1','part2','part3','part4','part5'],
  navigationTooltips:['5','4','3','2','1'],
  showActiveTooltip: true,
})
```

```html
<ul id='menu' style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0;">
  <li data-menuanchor="part1"><a href="#part1"  style="display: none;"></a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="part2"><a href="#part2"  style="padding-top: 0px;"><span>OUR SERVICES</span></a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="part3"><a href="#part3" ><span>OUR COMPANY</span></a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="part4"><a href="#part4" ><span>SWIFT CONSERVATION</span></a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="part5"><a href="#part5" ><span>BLOGS</span></a></li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Create a working example and then I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically overwrite the default CSS with your own. 
For example, to use red bullets:

```
#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
    background: red;
}
```

You can see the styles applied by default on the css file:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/src/fullpage.css

You can also find a tens of predefined navigaiton bullets to purchase on the [fullpage.js extensions](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/) page.

Comment: No i already customized the navigation dots by using by own custom css properties to make it look like story telling theme but the problem is that i want to show the last dot active when i am on my first section. Is it possible to do so? I tried reverting data-anchors but that didnt work

Comment: Just add the `active` class to the element itself. You can see how fullPage adds it too when moving from one section to another.

Comment: Currently my first nav dot represent my first section but i want that ny first dot should represent the last section ! If i am adding active class the dot number is still the same with the section they associate. I want first dot to navigate to last section and last dot to navigate to first section

Comment: If you want to play with the nav in such a way I would encourage you to create your custom nav element and then using fullpage.js callbacks or state classes to change its active nav when scrolling up or down. Then use methods to bind the click event.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733560/fullpage-js-change-dotted-nav-to-icon-set/36742906#36742906

Comment: I want to add a small photo at the end of nav dots is it possible to do so ?? Because the spans are dynamically adding to html using js then how can i add img at the end of the nav dots ?

Comment: Many things are possible with the right knowledge! However that's an issue for a totally different question. Not related with fullpage.js at all.